# Why the modification of http header not work in CEF?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chromium-embedded

I implemented CefRequestHandler interface. In the OnBeforeBrowse method I want to add custom http header but it seems not work. The related code as below

```
virtual bool OnBeforeBrowse( CefRefPtr< CefBrowser > browser, CefRefPtr< CefFrame > frame,
    CefRefPtr< CefRequest > request, CefRequestHandler::NavType navType, bool isRedirect )
{
    CefRequest::HeaderMap hdrMap;
    request->GetHeaderMap(hdrMap);

    hdrMap.insert(std::make_pair("Test", "test"));
    request->SetHeaderMap(hdrMap);
    return false;
}
```

The request parameter is passed as a pointer so I think the action performed on it should take effect, but actually not.

I'm new to use CEF library, I want't to know is there a way to add custom header before navigation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify request there:
[CefRequestHandler::OnBeforeBrowse()](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefRequestHandler.html#OnBeforeBrowse%28CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefFrame%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefRequest%3E,bool%29)

but try to implement this:
[CefRequestHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad()](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefRequestHandler.html#OnBeforeResourceLoad%28CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefFrame%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefRequest%3E%29)